# Inclusion between rings after localization

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $\phi:A \to B $ an injective finite ring map between two noetherian integral domains $A,B$. Let $ C \subset B$ a subring of $B$ and assume that there exist a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subset A$ , such that for the induced map on localizations $\phi_p:A_{\mathfrak{p} } \to B_{\mathfrak{p} }:= B \otimes_A A_{\mathfrak{p} }$ the ring $\widetilde{C}_{\mathfrak{p} }$ - which we *define* as the subring of $ B_{\mathfrak{p} }$ generated by $ C$ - is contained in the image $\phi_p(A_{\mathfrak{p}})$.

*Question:* Does in that case always exist a $ t \in A- \mathfrak{p}$ with $\phi(t) \in C $ such that $C_t$ - that means $C$ localized at $t$ - is contained in the image of $A_t$ under $\phi$?

The problem: even if the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ is finitely generated since the ring A is noetherian, this not neccessary holds for the multiplicative system  $ A- \mathfrak{p}$, so I see no direct way how to construct this $ t$ I'm looking for.

*Rmk #1:* the finiteness assumpion on $ \phi$ is neccessary, i.e. that $B$ is finite A-module, otherwise there is an obvious counterexample: let $ \phi$ the localization $A \to A_{\mathfrak{p} } =: B$ and let $C=B$.
*Rmk #2:* If the question is still too broad or the answer is negative, then one could also ask a 'baby' version of the problem by *additionally* assuming that $C$ is morevover a $A$- algebra such that $\widetilde{C}_{\mathfrak{p} }$ is given as  $C_{\mathfrak{p} }=C \otimes_A A_{\mathfrak{p} }$.

I asked an  [identical question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4627340/inclusion-of-rings-after-localization)  without getting an satisfying answer.